# Определение видимых и невидимых граней

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

Использую JOGL (Java OpenGL). У меня есть вертящийся с помощью `glRotatef` параллелепипед. Я его рисую вот так:

```
 private void drawCenteredCube(GL2 gl) {
   int height = (int) SizeUtil.getHeight();
   int width = (int) SizeUtil.getWidth();
   int depth = (int) SizeUtil.getDepth();

   gl.glColor4f(0.4f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 0);
   drawSquareFace(gl, height, depth, width);   // бок

   gl.glColor4f(0.09f, 0.095f, 0.095f, 0);
   gl.glRotatef(90, 1, 0, 0);
   drawSquareFace(gl, height, width, depth);   // зад

   gl.glColor4f(0.61f, 0.05f, 0.1f, 0);
   gl.glRotatef(90, 0, 1, 0);
   drawSquareFace(gl, depth, width, height);   // низ

   gl.glRotatef(90, 0, 1, 0);
   ForegroundUtil.paint(gl, 0, 0, depth / 2);  // лицо

   gl.glColor4f(0.4f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 0);
   gl.glRotatef(90, 1, 0, 0);
   drawSquareFace(gl, height, depth, width);  // бок

   gl.glColor4f(0.61f, 0.05f, 0.1f, 0);
   gl.glRotatef(90, 0, 1, 0);
   drawSquareFace(gl, width, depth, height);   // верх

   gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
 }
```

Проблема в том, что у меня постоянно некоторые части фигуры рисуются поверх других, хотя на самом деле их не должно быть видно в конкретный момент времени. Как понять, когда какие грани рисовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Емнип, для включения:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL); //функция сравнения глубины - на ваше усмотрение
```

для очистки

```
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Comment: Я изменил метод `display`. Было так:

             gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
Стало так:
    
             gl.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
             gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

Действительно, теперь ненужное не рисует. Но зато дико мерцает на текстурах (на гранях без текстур всё нормально).

Comment: `gl.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);`, кстати, достаточно один раз вызвать. если вы его не включаете/выключаете в процессе отрисовки кадра.

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно, можно один раз. Я уже пользовался функцией `glEnable` (для того, чтобы положить текстуру). А что делать с мерцанием?

Comment: а вы покажите, что у вас в `ForegroundUtil.paint` и `drawSquareFace`, может найдем проблему.

Comment: @Nofate, я открыл [новый вопрос](http://hashcode.ru/questions/51077) (про мерцание).

Comment: дада, уже смотрю

Answer (score 2):

это вам нужно буфер глубины включить

Comment: А как это сделать? Есть пример?