# Мерцание плоскости с текстурой

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

Есть вертящийся параллелепипед. В аниматоре он каждый раз поворачивается на 1/16 по каждой из осей координат. Плюс пользователь клавиатурой может вертеть модель на 1.0 за нажатие.

Воспользовавшись советом в теме "[Определение видимых и невидимых граней](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/)", включил свойство `GL_DEPTH_TEST`. Теперь видны только нужные грани. Но грань, на которой есть изображения дико мерцает. Как от этого избавиться?

**Добавлено.**

Я, **кажется**, понял, в чем проблема. На лицевой грани на одной и той же плоскости рисуется несколько примитивов (и тут не имеет значения, картинка это или прямоугольник). Только я всё равно не знаю, как от этого избавиться.

Метод `drawSquareFace`:

```
 private void drawSquareFace(GL2 gl, int width, int height, int depth) {
   gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
   gl.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
   gl.glVertex3f(-width / 2, -height / 2, depth / 2);
   gl.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
   gl.glVertex3f(-width / 2, height / 2, depth / 2);
   gl.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
   gl.glVertex3f(width / 2, height / 2, depth / 2);
   gl.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
   gl.glVertex3f(width / 2, -height / 2, depth / 2);
   gl.glEnd();
 }
```

Класс `ForegroundUtil`:

```
import javax.media.opengl.GL2;

public class ForegroundUtil {
    private static int myX;
    private static int myY;
    private static int myZ;

    public static void paint(GL2 gl, int x, int y, int z) {
        myX = x;
        myY = y;
        myZ = z;

        paintPhone(gl);
        paintDisplayOff(gl);

       ImageFromFile logoImage = new ImageFromFile("samsung1.jpg");
        logoImage.paint(gl, SizeUtil.getLogoWidth(), SizeUtil.getLogoHeight(), SizeUtil.getLogoLeft(), SizeUtil.getLogoTop());

        ImageFromFile buttonsImage = new ImageFromFile("buttons.jpg");
        buttonsImage.paint(gl, SizeUtil.getButtonsWidth(), SizeUtil.getButtonsHeight(), SizeUtil.getButtonsLeft(), SizeUtil.getButtonsTop());
    }

    public static void paintPoly(GL2 gl, float w, float h, float left, float top) {
        gl.glBegin (GL2.GL_POLYGON);
        gl.glTexCoord2d (0, 0);
        vertexHack(gl, left, top, 0);
        gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 0);
        vertexHack(gl, left + w, top, 0);
        gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 1);
        vertexHack(gl, left + w, top - h, 0);
        gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 1);
        vertexHack(gl, left, top - h, 0);
        gl.glEnd ();
    }

    private static void paintRectangle(GL2 gl, float w, float h, float left, float top, float r, float g, float b) {
        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
        gl.glColor3f(r, g, b);
        vertexHack(gl, left,     top,     0);
        vertexHack(gl, left + w, top,     0);
        vertexHack(gl, left + w, top + h, 0);
        vertexHack(gl, left,     top + h, 0);
        gl.glEnd();
    }

    private static void vertexHack(GL2 gl, float x, float y, float z) {
        // почему-то просто так не работало (этот хак меняет местами х и у)
        // когда всё заработает, постараюсь избавиться этого.
        // скорее всего неверный угол или ширину с высотой попутал. 
        gl.glVertex3f(y + myX,     x + myY,   z + myZ);
    }

    public static void paintPhone(GL2 gl) {
        float phoneWidth = SizeUtil.getWidth();
        float phoneHeight = SizeUtil.getHeight();
        paintRectangle(gl, phoneWidth, phoneHeight, -SizeUtil.getShiftX(), -SizeUtil.getShiftY(), 0.09f, 0.095f, 0.095f);
    }

    private static void paintDisplayOff(GL2 gl) {
        float displayWidth = SizeUtil.getDisplayWidth();
        float displayHeight = SizeUtil.getDisplayHeight();
        float left = SizeUtil.getDisplayLeft();
        float top  = SizeUtil.getDisplayTop();
        paintRectangle(gl, displayWidth, displayHeight, left, top, 0.17f, 0.17f, 0.21f);
    }

}
```

Класс, выводящий изображения:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.media.opengl.GL;
import javax.media.opengl.GL2;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class ImageFromFile {
    private float myWidth;
    private float myHeight;
    private ByteBuffer myByteBuffer;

    public ImageFromFile(String fileName) {
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;

        try {
            bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(fileName));
            myWidth = bufferedImage.getWidth();
            myHeight = bufferedImage.getHeight();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        WritableRaster raster =
            Raster.createInterleavedRaster(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE,
                  (int) myWidth,
                  (int) myHeight,
                  4,
                  null);
        ComponentColorModel colorModel=
            new ComponentColorModel (ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB),
                    new int[] {8, 8, 8, 8},
                    true,
                    false,
                    ComponentColorModel.TRANSLUCENT,
                    DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
        BufferedImage dukeImg =
            new BufferedImage (colorModel,
                    raster,
                    false,
                    null);

        Graphics2D g = dukeImg.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(bufferedImage, null, null);
        DataBufferByte dukeBuf =
            (DataBufferByte)raster.getDataBuffer();
        byte[] dukeRGBA = dukeBuf.getData();
        myByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(dukeRGBA);
        myByteBuffer.position(0);
        myByteBuffer.mark();
    }

    public void paint(GL2 gl, double width, double  height, double left, double top) {
        gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 13);
        gl.glPixelStorei(GL.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL2.GL_CLAMP);
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL2.GL_CLAMP);
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexEnvf(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL.GL_REPLACE);
        gl.glTexImage2D (GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.GL_RGBA, (int) myWidth, (int) myHeight, 0, GL.GL_RGBA,
                GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, myByteBuffer);

        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glBindTexture (GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 13);

        ForegroundUtil.paintPoly(gl, (float) width, (float) height, (float) left, (float) top);
        gl.glDisable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
}
```

При попытке снять скриншот, сохраняется такое изображение:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, вы на каждую отрисовку заново загружаете текстуры из файла и грузите ее в видео-память. Это не приводит к мерцанию, но все же нехорошо.

Во-вторых, вы не используете `glGenTextures`, а используете в качестве параметра `glBindTexture` свои константы. Это не криминально, не приводит к мерцанию, но тоже не лучшая практика, как и любые волшебные числа.

В-третьих, мерцание, вероятнее всего, связано с тем, что вы рисуете полигон передней панели, экран, клавиатуру и логотип в одной плоскости, что приводит к неопределенности: на один и тот же пиксель претендует и фрагмент текстуры и фрагмент полигона. Попробуйте сделать общую текстуру для всей лицевой панели и выводить один текстурированный полигон - мерцать не должно. Другой вариант - сместите плоскости экрана, логотипа и клавы на некоторое минимальное расстояние от корпуса.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв. Я вот попробовал так: сначала рисуем панель, потом увеличиваем `myZ` (`myZ++`). И потом рисуем всё остальное. Просто по заданию мне надо будет выводить на экран анимацию...

Comment: Да, это выход. Хотя, если вы будете рисовать анимацию на экране, то вам наверное потребуется рендеринг в текстуру. А в таком случае можно будет целиком компоновать текстуру передней панели с текущим кадром на экране и рисовать ее одним полигоном.

Зы. У вас слишком много кода в процедурном стиле. Попробуйте его ООПизировать )